# TSC_DEADLINE disabled during installation?

Tags: usb-installation

This question has being asked before but I didn't find any solution how to fix it. I ran into this issue during installation. After installing Ubuntu, it stuck here during reboot. Someone mentioned to login to root shell to update something but how to do it in the middle of boot?

Please don't just simply close this issue as the previous ticket. At lease provide a link to the solution if this is known or solved issue.